# How i make the code skip to a certain point in a if-statement

Tags: python-2.7, if-statement

I'm working on a basic game. I'd like to know how I can make the code go to a specific point in the code/if-statement, rather than starting off at the beginning.

For example, in my code at line 19: `kithcen()` I don't want to redirect it to the start of the if-statement; again going on the describe the kitchen and then asking for an input: `choice02 = raw_input("What do you do?")`, but rather i want it to directly skip to the input part.

```
def kitchen():
    print "You see a dusty old kitchen, nobody has probably used it for quite a while."
    print "There are 3 different cupboards(0, 1, 2) or a letter(3) placed on the counter."
    choice02 = raw_input("What do you do? >")

    if choice02 == "0" or choice02 == "first cupboard" or choice02 == "check first cupboard" or choice02 == "open first cupboard":
        print "You see a dusty empty bottles of milks, with spiderwebs at the corners of the cupboard. Nothing of Interest here."
        raw_input(">")
        kitchen()

    elif choice02 == "1" or choice02 == "second cupbaord" or choice02 == "check second cupboard" or choice02 == "open second cupboard":
        print "You see some packs of likely expired cereal and a key(0)."
        choice_02_A = raw_input("What do you do? >")

   #----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
        if choice02_A == "pick key" or choice02_A == "key" or choice02_A == "0" or choice02_A == "get key":
            print "You picked the key. This probably unlocks some door."
            raw_input("> ")
            kitchen()

        elif choice02_A == "close cupboard" or choice02_A == "kitchen" or choice02_A == "go back to kitchen":
            kitchen()

        else:
            print "Not a valid option."
   #-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#

    elif choice02 == "2" or choice02 == "third cupboard" or choice02 == "check third cupboard" or choice02 == "open third cupboard":
        print "You see an empty or dusty cupboard. Nothing of interest here."
        raw_input("> ")
        kitchen()

    elif choice02 == "3" or choice02 == "check letter" or choice02 == "letter" or choice02 == "read letter":
        print """
        You read the letter:
        \n"Dear Shawn............\n"
        It makes no sense to you.
        """


    elif choice02 == "go back" or choice02 == "entrance hall" or choice02 == "go to entrance hall":
        entrance_hall()

else:
    "Not a valid Option."
```

Comment: Indent your code properly

Comment: Also, you keep saying "loop" in your question. What loop?

Comment: Sorry, my bad, I'm new. A misconception, anyways I made a edit. 
The indentation go messed up a bit while copying.

Comment: No worries. Also, please indent. The code as it stands is not valid Python. Specifically, everything after `def` needs to be up one level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see no loop, but if you only want the print statements when you call the function from outside, you could have an optional boolean like this:

```
def kitchen(already_there=False):
    if not already_there:
        print('...')
    choice02 = raw_input("What do you do? >")

    # ...

    elif # ...
        # ...
        kitchen(already_there=True)
```

Comment: This is especially nice because it is backwards compatible with any code you've already written.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider refactoring your code and using dictionaries to avoid long if-else statements.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/27365077/2884613.

```
print "There are 3 different cupboards(0, 1, 2) or a letter(3) placed on the counter." 

alias = {
  '0': '0',
  'first cupboard': '0',
  'check first cupboard': '0',
  'open first cupboard': '0',
  '1': '1',
  'second cupboard': '1',
  'check second cupboard':'1',
  ...
}

dic = {
  "0":"You see a dusty empty bottles of milks, with spiderwebs at the corners of the cupboard. Nothing of Interest here.",  \
  "1":"You see some packs of likely expired cereal and a key(0).",  \
  "2":"You see an empty or dusty cupboard. Nothing of interest here."
  ...
}

while(True):
  choice02 = raw_input("What do you do? >")
  if choice02 in alias:
    print dic[alias[choice02]]
    break
  else:
    print "Not a valid option"
```

Comment: Alright, Thanks! This is definitely cleaner.
Though how could I assign multiple keys to a single value/string

Comment: Hmm, one possibility is to use two dictionaries. One to store the alias key association and one to store your actual data.  I'll update my answer shortly.